# Scala Iterable Memory Leaks

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, iterable

I recently started playing with Scala and ran across the following. Below are 4 different ways to iterate through the lines of a file, do some stuff, and write the result to another file. Some of these methods work as I would think (though using a lot of memory to do so) and some eat memory to no end.

The idea was to wrap Scala's getLines Iterator as an Iterable. I don't care if it reads the file multiple times - that's what I expect it to do.

Here's my repro code:

```
class FileIterable(file: java.io.File) extends Iterable[String] {
  override def iterator = io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines
}

// Iterator

// Option 1: Direct iterator - holds at 100MB
def lines = io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines

// Option 2: Get iterator via method - holds at 100MB
def lines = new FileIterable(file).iterator

// Iterable

// Option 3: TraversableOnce wrapper - holds at 2GB
def lines = io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines.toIterable

// Option 4: Iterable wrapper - leaks like a sieve
def lines = new FileIterable(file)

def values = lines
      .drop(1)
      //.map(l => l.split("\t")).map(l => l.reduceLeft(_ + "|" + _))
      //.filter(l => l.startsWith("*"))

val writer = new java.io.PrintWriter(new File("out.tsv"))
values.foreach(v => writer.println(v))
writer.close()
```

The file it's reading is ~10GB with 1MB lines.

The first two options iterate the file using a constant amount of memory (~100MB). This is what I would expect. The downside here is that an iterator can only be used once and it's using Scala's call-by-name convention as a psuedo-iterable. (For reference, the equivalent c# code uses ~14MB)

The third method calls toIterable defined in TraverableOnce. This one works, but it uses about 2GB to do the same work. No idea where the memory is going because it can't cache the entire Iterable.

The fourth is the most alarming - it immediately uses all available memory and throws an OOM exception. Even weirder is that it does this for all of the operations I've tested: drop, map, and filter. Looking at the implementations, none of them seem to maintain much state (though the drop looks a little suspect - why does it not just count the items?). If I do no operations, it works fine.

My guess is that somewhere it's maintaining references to each of the lines read, though I can't imagine how. I've seen the same memory usage when passing Iterables around in Scala. For example if I take case 3 (.toIterable) and pass that to a method that writes an Iterable[String] to a file, I see the same explosion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note how the [ScalaDoc of `Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html) says:

> Implementations of this trait need to provide a concrete method with
>   signature:
>
> ```
>   def iterator: Iterator[A]
> ```
>
> They also need to provide a method `newBuilder` which creates a builder
>   for collections of the same kind.

Since you don't provide an implementation for `newBuilder`, you get the default implementation, which uses a `ListBuffer` and thus tries to fit everything into memory.

You might want to implement `Iterable.drop` as

```
def drop(n: Int) = iterator.drop(n).toIterable
```

but that would break with the representation invariance of the collection library (i.e. `iterator.toIterable` returns a `Stream`, while you want `List.drop` to return a `List` etc - thus the need for the `Builder` concept).

Comment: Interesting... I'm coming from c# where all that is taken care of. Out of curiosity - why would they choose to buffer the entire sequence as the default option?

Comment: Does this also mean that when I pass a sequence as an Iterable[T] parameter that it will by default be buffered? If so, doesn't that defeat the purpose? I was under the impression that the data would only be buffered in memory when I explicitly ask for it via toList, toArray, etc..

Comment: I'm not really qualified to comment on the design of the collection library (the standard introduction to the topic is [here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scala_collections_architecture.html)). You're really only running into problems because you're trying to extend Iterable, you'd be fine with a Stream or Iterator.